# Why is a Django sqlite db file getting wiped out by a Python script?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I've looked through quite a few questions on this one already and have not found a solution for my particular case. The issue I'm currently facing is my sqlite db file is getting wiped out when I try to save() to insert a new row from an Python script. However, this does not happen when using the same steps from one of my Django apps.

Is there some additional setup I need to have in place in order to use my Django model work with an external Python script that is not mentioned below?

In the Python script I've already added the following to the top of the file:

```
sys.path.append(my_project_path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='settings'
from django.conf import settings
```

I've also double-checked on the following items:

1. My settings module has the absolute path for the NAME of the db.
2. When I rm the DB file and run python manage.py syncdb the table I
   desire is created; the DB file size is approximately 50k after this
   initialization.

This is the behavior I'm seeing:

- After running Item 2 above, I can successfully create new rows for my table from my Django app.
- After running Item 2 above, when use the Django model from the Python script I receive a DatabaseError stating there is "no such table". Additionally, the sqlite db file goes to a zero size when this occurs.

Is there anything I'm missing on being able to use the Django model from another Python script? I'm using this script as a tool for some manual updates and would really like to get it working.

Here's a quick example of my setup:

Directories:

```
myproject/
myproject/myapp/
myproject/tools/
```

The Django model resides myproject/myapp/ and the script resides in myproject/tools/. The PYTHONPATH includes myproject/. In the script, I have the following:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(absolute_path_to_myproject)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='settings'
from django.conf import settings

import myapp.models

my_model = myapp.models.my_model(name = 'TestName')
my_model.save()
```

Comment: Turns out this issue was due to something else in the environment corrupting the file and was not related to the code.

Answer (score -1):

You were not detailed enough your setup, but it sounds like there is a better way to do it.

Django already manages database connections for you, so there's no need to address the actual sqlite file. Just run your script in a django session using "python manage.py my_script". Here's the way to do it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: I wasn't trying to address the sqlite file directly and is why I'm importing the django settings as mentioned above. What I mentioned was the observation of the final state that the sqlite file has been reduced to a 0 size after I reach the "no such table" DatabaseError. I'm still ramping up on Django and haven't used the management commands yet so I tried them out for this scenario. Even when invoking this from manage.py the same issue still occurs. Will update the question with an example of my current setup.